# how to calculate percentage with nested dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, nested-loops

I'm stuck with how to calculate percentages with nested dictionary. I have a `dictionay` defined by `old_dict = {'X': {'a': 0.69, 'b': 0.31}, 'Y': {'a': 0.96, 'c': 0.04}}`, and I know the percentage of `X`and `Y` are in the table:

```
input= {"name":['X','Y'],"percentage":[0.9,0.1]}
table = pd.DataFrame(input)

OUTPUT:
   name percentage
0   X   0.9
1   Y   0.1
```

But I hope to use the percentage of X and Y to multiply by a,b, c separately. That is, `X*a = 0.9*0.69`, `X*b = 0.9*0.31`,`Y*a = 0.1*0.96`, `Y*c = 0.1*0.04`... so that I can find the mixed percentage of a, b, and c, and finally got a new dictionary `new_dict = {'a': 0.717, 'b': 0.279 ,'c': 0.004}`.

I'm struggling with how to break through the nested dictionary and how to link X and Y with the corresponding value in the table. Can anyone help me? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You could use a DataFrame for the first dictionary and a Series for the second and perform an aligned multiplication, then `sum`:

```
old_dict = {'X': {'a': 0.69, 'b': 0.31}, 'Y': {'a': 0.96, 'c': 0.04}}
df = pd.DataFrame(old_dict)

inpt = {"name":['X','Y'],"percentage":[0.9,0.1]}
table = pd.DataFrame(inpt)

# convert table to series:
ser = table.set_index('name')['percentage']
# alternative build directly a Series:
# ser = pd.Series(dict(zip(*inpt.values())))

# compute expected values:
out = (df*ser).sum(axis=1).to_dict()
```

output: `{'a': 0.717, 'b': 0.279, 'c': 0.004}`

Comment: Thank you! This is a cool way! But I'm wondering why I only got `{'a': 0.0, 'b': 0.0, 'c': 0.0}` when I changed `X` and `Y` to `MAIN FABRIC` and  `SECONDARY FABRIC`, which are the true variable names I need? Also, when we change the variable names, say, change `Y` to `M`, the answer also changes! That's weird!

Comment: @Vivian the variable names should match. Or use `(df*ser.values)` instead of `(df*ser)`

Comment: Thank you mozway! This time it works! I picked up something new!