# calculate sum of product between values in a dictionary and the other nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I want to calculate the sum of product between values of dictionary A and the values in nested dictionary B. To be specific,

```
Dict_A = {'Apple': 0.909, 'Pear': 0.091}
Dict_B = {'Egg': {'a': 0.69, 'b': 0.31},'Bread': {'a': 0.96, 'c': 0.04}}
```

Apple corresponds with Egg, Pear corresponds with Bread.

I hope to multiply Apple by a and b in Egg, and multiply Pear by a and c in Bread, and finally, I hope to find the sum of same a, b, and c. So the output should be:

```
OUTPUT = {'a': 0.717, 'b': 0.279, 'c': 0.004}
*where:
a = 0.909*0.69 + 0.091*0.96
b = 0.909*0.31
c = 0.091*0.04
```

I referred to a relevant question in this link: [how to calculate percentage with nested dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70761321/how-to-calculate-percentage-with-nested-dictionary) , which both aim to solve questions about the nested dictionary. But I'm still struggling with how to connect series, dictionaries, and DataFrame to more conveniently compute the sum of products.

Comment: See [how do I ask and answer homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions). You need to make a genuine attempt at solving it on your own before asking for help here

Comment: Hey, thanks for your suggestion, but no need to criticize in this way okay?

Comment: There is definitely a need. I'm not trying to be rude or harsh, but your question is essentially "here's my homework problem can someone solve it for me?" SO isn't a code writing service. If you read the previous link you can find guidelines on what is generally accepted for asking homework questions

Comment: I read it for sure because that was the question I asked! I'm just looking for some different approaches to solve similar questions, please don't be the god and try to teach others what to do. GOOD LUCK!

Answer (score 1):

I think this should do the trick :

```
result_dic = {}
for x in zip(Dict_A.items(), Dict_B.items()):
    coef = x[0][1]
    for k, v in x[1][1].items():
        if k not in result_dic:
            result_dic[k] = v*coef
        else:
            result_dic[k] += v*coef

print({key: round(result_dic[key], 3) for key in result_dic})
```